# bottle and pywin32 not working properly together

Tags: python, python-3.x, bottle, pywin32

So, I'm studying Python and therefore a noob question maybe.
I'm trying run bottle from within a windows service.
If I run bottle standlone, works great, if I run the windows service works great too.
But when I try to import bottle and start the service I get the error:

```
File "C:\Users\my.username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\bottle.py", line 74, in <module>
    _stdout, _stderr = sys.stdout.write, sys.stderr.write
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'
```

This is the code I've tried so far:

```
import bottle #just adding this line raises the exception
import win32serviceutil
import win32service
import win32event
import servicemanager
import logging
import threading


class AppServerSvc(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = 'PestService'
    _svc_display_name_ = 'The Pest Service'
    _svc_description_ = "This service writes stuff to a file"

    def __init__(self, args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_RUNNING)
        win32event.WaitForSingleObject(self.hWaitStop, win32event.INFINITE)
        self.main()

    def main(self):
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(AppServerSvc)
```

Simply adding 'import bottle' raises the exception.
I'm little lost. I've searched Google, but to be honest I don't have a clue on what to search...
Like I said, separating service from bottle no problem. Both run just fine.

Comment: Might be that bottle expects stdout to be defined, but maybe it isn’t defined for a Windows service? You could try putting a `try/except AttributeError `around the import of bottle and then don’t raise

Comment: Nah, now pop up another exception. I think bottle is not meant to work like this..

Comment: I'm not quite sure that I understood the question. When does it work? When you remove the import ? But I don't see any `bottle` related code. Are you sure the module is properly installed? Note that you installed *Python* in your user's home folder. Usually services are run by *SYSTEM*, so you might get some *Access Denied* errors. How do you run the script?

Comment: It does work when I remove import bottle line. Need no bottle code to fail, just the import line is suffice to break. Altough Python is installed in my home folder, the service installation occurs flawlessly.